# Search whois for .ai tld domains to avoid front running

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, top-level-domains, whois

Recently found a nice `.ai` domain name available for my project on NameCheap, but found that it had been registered when I went to purchase it the next day, with the owner asking me to "place a starting bid" to purchase it from him. I'm worried about front-running attacks on future domain name ideas, and I've read elsewhere that querying domain names directly using something like `whois` on the terminal is a safer method.

`whois` does not seem to support querying for `.ai` domains. Are there any workarounds or alternative methods?